# The space of entire functions is finite-dimensional?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

I want to prove that linear operator T$: H(C) \to H(C)$ ($H(C)$ - space of entire functions) $(T(f))(z) = zf(z)$ is continuous. Can I use a fact that any linear operator in finite-dimensional space is continuous?

Comment: The space of entire functions is definitely not finite dimensional.

Comment: Even the subspace of polynomials is not!

Comment: Are you interested in a proof that does *not* use this assumption? (you should change your title if so)

Comment: @preferred_anon is it okey on this site? I think i need to create new question

Comment: @OuoDoulo It would not be a bad idea to create a new question, since this one has already attracted an answer.

Comment: Also, the question is not quite well-defined until you specify the _topology_ you want on the space of entire functions...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every polynomial is an entire function.

Thus, clearly, the space of entire functions is infinite-dimensional.
The basis must be at least the size of $\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: @QuantumSpace, perhaps you didn't write what you meant, since (by Liouville's theorem) the collection of bounded entire functions consists precisely of constants... :)

Comment: @paulgarrett Thanks, was stupid.

Comment: It is even easy to prove that the dimension of $H(\Bbb C)$ is the cardinality of the continuum. Is there some duplicate about that?

Comment: Plesase do not answer questions wwithout context. https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards?cb=1